# Прописная или строчная буква в названиях устройств, в том числе вымышленных: какому правилу следовать?

Tags: семантика, прописная-строчная, ономастика, оформление-текста, редактура

Остро встал вопрос: как писать названия устройств, которые имеют переносные (непрямые) названия, да и вообще специфических устройств как таковых? Вот есть, например, фильм и сериал "Звёздные врата". Их сюжет строится вокруг фантастического устройства инопланетян, которое позволяет путешествовать на другие планеты (если там тоже есть звёздные врата). Но как должно правильно писаться название устройства? Оба слова с прописной? Первое с прописной? Оба со строчной (ведь устройство серийное, условно говоря, как смартфон)? Причём звёздные врата изобретены древней исчезнувшей цивилизацией, которая понаставила их по планетам Млечного Пути (и не только), и само их название у многих рас галактики отличается (чаппа'ай, астриа порта, круг стоячей воды и др.). Так как писать все эти названия по правилам русского языка?

Мне кажется, что названия серийных или распространённых устройств следует писать со строчной при прочих равных (как козья ножка у Чехова в "Хирургии" — инструмент для удаления зубов, или тот же перпетуум-мобиле — гипотетический вечный двигатель). Насколько это верное рассуждение?

Другое дело — устройства уникальные, в единственном экземпляре, названия которых сродни прозвищу или имени (как имена мечей, скажем). Тут надо как минимум первое слово писать с прописной, а может, и все, кроме служебных. К примеру, во вселенной Вархаммер 40 000 существует Золотой Трон — устройство, внешняя часть которого (своего рода седалище оператора) действительно выглядит как золотой трон, но суть сего конструкта до конца неясна; он как минимум в целом позволяет оператору (точнее, практически единственному на это способному человеку — Императору) управлять колоссальными потоками энергии, направляя их по своему разумению. Есть и Астрономикон — своего рода уникальный маяк галактического масштаба, который указывает звездолётам свет во тьме варпа — специфического подпространства, населённого чудовищными сущностями, через который корабли проходят, чтобы сократить путь из пункта А в пункт Б в реальном мире.

Но есть существенный нюанс. Если вернуться к тем же звёздным вратам, то бывает там такое: некая раса живёт на планете и знать не знает, что за штука у них тут стоит. Тогда логично название, которым они именуют свои звёздные врата (ну, тот же Круг Стоячей Воды) писать с прописной (и все слова в этом названии, кроме служебных), ведь в понимании тех, кто их так назвал, это предмет в единственном экземпляре (могут считать его даром богов, святилищем, древним памятником архитектуры — чем угодно). А если местные жители знают функционал устройства и что оно не единственное, но называют по-своему, надо писать это их название со строчной (круг стоячей воды). Логично ведь?

Проще говоря, можно ли обобщить и сказать, что при прочих равных названия серийных устройств или устройств, существующих не в единственном экземпляре, следует писать со строчной, а устройств уникальных — надо смотреть, но скорее всего с прописной? Теоретически ведь, даже если устройство было серийным, но осталось одним-единственным на свете из себе подобных, тут можно и так, и так, надо по ситуации и контексту смотреть. Что вы об этом думаете?

Дополню вопрос. Правильно получается, что если раса называет звёздные врата (серийное устройство, имя нарицательное) Кругом Стоячей Воды (считает, например, святилищем, имя собственное), то все буквы тут пишутся с прописной? Потому что здесь всё в переносном смысле (это не стоячая вода, а горизонт событий червоточины, просто выглядит похоже)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, зачем все так осложнять. Этот вопрос имеет **грамматическое решение**, из него и надо исходить в каждом конкретном случае.

Если раса считает, что ***Звездные врата***  — это единственный предмет, то для них это индивидуальное (условное) название, то есть имя собственное. Если бы они знали, что их много, то это было бы нарицательное название  — ***звездные врата,*** а какое-нибудь условное имя  они могли бы им придумать. Это было бы именем собственным.

**Грамматическая справка**

Имена существительные делятся на следующие лексико-грамматические разряды: **собственные и нарицательные**.

Имена существительные **нарицательные** – это название предмета как представителя целого класса однородных предметов: город, озеро, мальчик, дерево.

Имена существительные **собственные** – это индивидуальные названия предметов, **выделяемых из ряда однородных предметов,** например: Москва, Байкал, Александр.

К именам собственным **принадлежат** имена лиц, географические и астрономические названия, а также другие группы индивидуальных имен.

Предмет, имеющий собственное название, в то же время имеет и **родовое наименование,** обозначаемое нарицательным существительным: город Москва.

Имена собственные могут **переходить** в нарицательные, употребляясь как обобщенное название целого класса предметов: геркулес, донжуан.

Comment: В фантастике и фэнтези нередко пишут с заглавной буквы нарицательное существительное, смысл которого отличается от обычного. К примеру, *Врата* в "Звёздной тени" Лукьяненко — их много, Врат, это не наименование конкретных Врат, а класс объектов. Тем не менее всюду пишется с заглавной, чтобы, видимо, отличить от обычного смысла слова "врата". Получается, что Врата — это класс объектов, выделяемый из более широкого класса объектов ("врата" в общепринятом смысле). Делаю вывод, что необязательно, чтобы называемый с заглавной буквы  предмет или объект был непременно в единственном числе.

Comment: У того же Лукьяненко в Дозорах: всюду *Иные* пишется с заглавной. Есть люди, а есть Иные.

Comment: Тогда надо писать по правилам § 24. Названия марок машин и механизмов  http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=28#pp28.  Там есть понятия имен собственных – ледокол «Адмирал Макаров», но прописная буква используется и  в официальных серийных названиях самолетов, а это не имена собственные для единичных предметов. К тому же в неофициальных названиях они пишутся со строчной буквы (в кавычках или без кавычек). Тогда Иные –  это серийное название людей с особыми свойствами, но не единичные названия (у каждого есть свое индивидуальное имя). То же самое можно сказать о Вратах – название серии.

Comment: Вот только собственных правил изобретать не надо, иначе каждый будет писать как ему нравится. то есть по своей логике.  Надо применять общие правила к конкретной ситуации.

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что все.2.  ПРОПИСНАЯ БУКВА
С прописной буквы пишутся следующие слова в составе имени собственного:
(1) первое слово;
(2) слова с индивидуальным, или условным,  значением имени;
(3) слова особой важности;
(4) другие имена собственные, входящие в данное составное имя.

3. СТРОЧНАЯ БУКВА
Со строчной буквы пишутся следующие слова в составе имени собственного:
(1) родовые наименования;
(2) другие слова с реальным, а не условным значением;
(3) служебные слова.

Comment: Пример: Речной вокзал.  Это имя собственное, Первое слово пишется с прописной буквы, а второе со строчной, так как имеет реальное, а не условное значение, к тому же это родовое название. Также: Российская академия наук.  Только первое слово с прописной, а остальные слова имеют реальное значение. Также Северный Ледовитый океан. Здесь второе слово является условным названием. Все слова в составе имени собственного надо проверять.

Comment: А Златые врата/Златые Врата по-разному можно написать, но надо учитывать традицию письма. А объяснение придумать нетрудно. Строчная – значит, это реальное значение слова, прописная– значить условное знаение или слово особой важности.

Comment: Это вполне разумное объяснение, здесь действительно все условно и метафорично, и тогда используются прописные буквы (нет ни одного слова, обозначающего реальный предмет).

Comment: А разве если в имени собственном все слова употреблены в переносном значении, не логичнее все слова и писать с прописной? Круг Стоячей Воды, или просто Круг. Звёздные Врата, или просто Врата (потому что это не врата, а межпространственный  портал, причём при активации устройства строится червоточина из точки А в точку Б, и нельзя попасть обратно в А; надо будет из точки Б заново активировать устройство, создав новую червоточину — из Б в А; так реальные врата/ворота явно не работают)...

Comment: Ну, врата еще могут иметь значение портала, там оба варианта возможны. А Круг Стоячей воды как-то мало напоминает вокзал.