# Прописная или строчная буква в переносных названиях (прозвищах) рас/национальностей/фракций, в том числе вымышленных?

Tags: семантика, прописная-строчная, ономастика, оформление-текста, редактура

Заметил, что во многих вымышленных вселенных есть расы/фракции, общеупотребительные названия которых носят условный характер — по той причине, что истинное название либо мало кому известно, либо это оно и есть, и они сами себя так называют. И в таких случаях верно ли, что подобные названия следует писать с прописной буквы (Древние — раса в "Звёздных вратах", Потоп и Предтечи — расы в Halo, Другие — фракция людей в "Остаться в живых", Клинки — своего рода орден/организация по защите императора в TES и др.)? По идее, это логично, ведь смысл названия здесь переносный, в некоторых случаях можно даже считать прозвищем расы. Но тогда почему переносные названия (прозвища) реальных рас и национальностей мы пишем со строчной — вопреки правилу о том, что все слова, кроме служебных, в прозвищах пишутся с прописной буквы?

Американцы — янки, ковбои; французы — лягушатники, картавые; немцы — фрицы, колбасники...

Из вымышленных: орки — зелёненькие; тау — синенькие; техножрецы (как представители фракции Адептус Механикус) — шестерёночки (всё это из вселенной Вархаммер 40 000)...

Так в чём же тут принципиальное отличие, которое велит в одних случаях писать подобные названия со строчной, а в других — с прописной?

На этот вопрос сподвигло, помимо прочего, обсуждение в комментариях темы о названиях устройств, в том числе вымышленных (см. [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470942/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%B0)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В русском языке все национальности и их прозвища считаются **нарицательными** существительными, относить их к именам собственным не имеет смысла: это не индивидуальные названия единичных предметов.

Но даже если считать их "серией", то в использовании прописной буквы тоже нет необходимости. Аналогично (как нарицательные названия) рассматриваются и прозвища. Значение этих слов вполне понятно пользователям языка.

2. В фантастике прозвища тоже являются нарицательными, но названия некоторых рас пишутся с прописной буквы.  Это тоже не собственные имена, а выбор прописной буквы носит **условный характер**.

Дело в том,что ***Древние, Потоп, Предтечи, Другие, Клинки*** нужно отличать от нарицательных существительных, которые также могут использоваться в тексте, а иначе трудно будет выделить название рас.